# JavaScript for form validation desn't seem to be getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate a form with JavaScript. It prints error messages when input fields are empty. The problem I'm having is that the code doesn't fire on submit.

http://jsfiddle.net/LHaav/

Here is the HTML code:

```
<head>
...
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/validate.js"></script>
....
</head>

...
      <form name="submitForm" method="post" id="submitBetaForm" onsubmit="return(validate())" action="validate.php" class="form-style">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" id="email-beta" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email"/>
        <label for="firstName">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="firstName" class="half-width" name="messageName"  placeholder="First name"/>
...
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function validate()
{
    var email = document.submitForm.email;
    var first = document.submitForm.firstName;
    var last = document.submitForm.lastName;
    var message = document.getElementById('warning');

    message.innerHTML = 'This is working!';

    var newLineCharNum = 0, poemContentArray = 0;
    //check to make sure that there is actually new line in the 
    //text area. Ensure that code doesn't blow up.
    if(textarea.value.match(/\n/g) != null)
    {
        newLineCharNum = textarea.value.match(/\n/g).length;
        poemContentArray = textarea.value.split("\n");
    }

    //check for email, firstName, lastName
    //focus puts the cursor on the element that needs to be corrected.
    var lineNum = newLineCharNum + 1;
    // if(email.value.length > 30)
    // {
    //     message.innerHTML = 'Email should be less than 30 character';
    //     title.focus();
    //     return false;
    // }
    else if(email.value.length == 0 || title == "")
    {
        message.innerHTML = 'Please enter your email';
        title.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (firstName.value.length > 30)
    {
        message.innerHTML = 'First name should be less than 30 character';
        authorName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(firstName.value.length == 0 ||authorName == "")
    {
        message.innerHTML = 'Please enter your first name';
        authorName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (lastName.value.length > 30)
    {
        message.innerHTML = 'Last name should be less than 30 character';
        authorName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(lastName.value.length == 0 ||authorName == "")
    {
        message.innerHTML = 'Please enter your last name';
        authorName.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

And PHP here:

```
<?php 

session_start();

include('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['SEND'])){

    //get information from the form
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $first_name = $_POST['messageName'];
    $last_name = $_POST['messageLast'];
    $interest = $_POST['interest'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];

    // Check connection
    if ($con)
    {
        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `interest`, `country`, `time`, `email`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$first_name', '$last_name', '$interest', '$country', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$email')";

        $con->query($insert_query);
        $con->close();
        echo "here";
    }
    else{
        echo "ERROR!";
    }

    //store informationn in the sessiont for later use
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
    $_SESSION['interest'] = $interest;
    $_SESSION['country'] = $country;

    }
```

?>

Comment: Creating a fiddle will make this easier to answer. I know this doesn't directly answer your question but the validation you're trying to execute can be taken care of using the HTML attributes `maxlength` and `required`. You may have reasons why you can't use these attributes but if not it may be something to consider.

Comment: Just a thought, how do you submit the form? If you use form.submit(); then the onsubmit handler is not called. You must use submit button and click on it!

Comment: @garethdn thanks for the reply here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LHaav/

Comment: If the code doesn't fire on submit it means that your form is being submitted anyway regardless the validation should prevent submission or the form is not getting submitted in any case?

Comment: @leandroico Makes sense but even commenting out action="validate.php" (that sends the data to data base) I still don't get the error message to display when there is an empty input field

Comment: The form works and local database is getting updated

Comment: I just need to be able to validate first so I dont get corrupted data on DB.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that your example is full of bad variable names and references. Your using `firstNmae` when you should be using `first`, for instance.

I've corrected some of them and it's apparently working: http://jsfiddle.net/LHaav/1/

You just have to be aware of the JS errors in your browser console and you'll be fine. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You got a good few problems in your Javascript - undefined variables everywhere. But the main problem is that your Javascript in that fiddle is not being executed at all. If you change your form handler to `onsubmit="return validate()"` you'll see that validate is not defined, although this may be down to how the JS is loaded in the fiddle.

Regardless, to alleviate this problem move your script out of the head and put it in the bottom of the page, just the before the closing `body` tag. You'll at least now hopefully hit the validate method.

http://jsfiddle.net/LHaav/2/

Now you'll have to take care of all those undefined variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by "validate is not defined"?

Comment: regardless of my js problems shouldn't <p id="warning"></p> get updated with     var message = document.getElementById('warning');

    message.innerHTML = 'This is working!';

Comment: By `validate is undefined` I mean that your JavaScript doesn't know what `validate` is because it hasn't been defined when your `onsubmit` callback tries to execute. Now, like i said, this could be just in the fiddle only and not in your code. The behaviour you want is working in the fiddle i posted. The difference is I'm logging it to the console. In Chrome hit F12 and go to the console tab. Submit your form (valid or invalid) and you will see `This is working!` get logged.